# Star Trek (2009), why does Nero not destroy the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, movie, star-trek-2009

In the movie, [Nero](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/nero) is 154 years ahead of the time, and allegedly uses Borg technology - a threat unknown to the Federation at the time. How is it possible that Nero doesn't simply destroy the Enterprise? The technology is way beyond the Enterprise.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Several reasons:

1. Nero initially doesn't *want* to destroy the Enterprise. He wants Spock to *suffer* first, which is why he deliberately inflicted less than fatal damage during his surprise volley.
2. His ship may be from more than a hundred years in the future and enhanced with Borg tech, but it's still a high-tech Borg-enhanced *mining barge*. He managed to annihilate the main fleet because he attacked from ambush, but in a straight up fight if they'd seen him coming he wouldn't have managed, in no small part because...
3. Frankly, just going by his observed behavior in the movie Nero is a fricking *moron* in terms of strategy, tactics, or ship command in general. It's understandable why his government didn't deem fit to trust him with anything more powerful than a mining barge.

Comment: They did trust him enough to give him a high-tech Borg-enhanced mining barge.

Comment: Nope. He modified said barge after Romulus was destroyed. +1 for Nero being a moron, though I'd create a dozen sock puppets for upvotes if you said Abrams instead of Nero.

Comment: It may have been modified after Romulus was destroyed, but it was done so by the [Tal Shiar](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Narada#Apocrypha).

Comment: I don't even think you need 2 & 3 - I'm pretty certain he tells Ayel that he wants Spock of this timeline to watch the destruction of Vulcan.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure about 2#. Remember that he defeated a group of 47+ Klingon Birds of Prey. That's a lot of Birds of Prey.

Comment: To be fair, all villains in star trek seem to be morons. Even ol Kahn the so called great does very little to prove his claims of superior anything... both old and new versions. If they were so great, they wouldn't be defeated in the span of a single movie.

Comment: @KaiQing: On the contrary, Khan showed engineering ability far beyond reasonable. His combat tactics on the other hand ...

Comment: @Joshua - I don't know. Scotty shows that as well but he's not referred to as great. Least not in the same way Khan is.

Comment: @KaiQing: Scottie didn't go from 20th century knowledge to understand 23rd century technical manuals in a day.

Comment: @Joshua - and he was still defeated immediately. By the number of life or death threatening scenarios the entire enterprise crew has faced and survived, the standard for superior has been raised so much that even an aptitude like Khan's wouldn't merit the fear and danger they write him as. But I get it. Star trek likes to write this way. I think Khan should have escaped and surfaced in another film, but budget and attention spans would probably not agree. All I'm saying is he wasn't done justice by the writers. Not the way he should have been.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a mining ship, that's why.

It has an advanced payload (apparently at least 25 years worth of guided missiles - so, like, 38) but its primary function is that of a simple mining ship. Enhance it all you like, but without a Constitution-refit style teardown/buildup again, it's still a workhorse, not a war machine. To invoke parable -- one could weld a chain gun to a 21st century bulldozer, but that doesn't mean one could travel back in time with it to change the entire outcome of the Civil War (at least not without better strategic planning than Nero executed).

As for the handwaving of Borg enhancements to explain the Narada's apparent superiority -- *eeeehhhh.* The stuff about Borg tech/Tal Shiar/etc is from the comic, and its legitimacy as canon is… iffy? I'm aware of the interview were someone (Orci?) stated it is, but that would be yet another anomaly in the concert of oddities that permit new Star Trek's unique rules about space, time, Federation guidelines for bridge lightning, and now apparently offscreen works to be permitted as 'canon'. Roddenberry was more or less the godfather of the retcon, but even where published works are considered to have certain grey areas, comics have a pretty hard and fast rule about being "right out", as it were. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_canon#Other_publications

Besides, since when did "Borg enhanced technology" include guided projectile weapons? The Borg's primary weapons are beam and energy weapons. Adaptive shielding, focused lasers and that. The Narada doesn't spend much (if any?) screen-time tearing into starships with its planet mining laser drill, so one can only really prove it relies on those fleet-seeking missile thingies (unless that's in the comic too, but I'll point to my previous statement on comics as canon).

Comment: Almost a +1 for *'eeeehhhh'*...

Answer (score 0):

Nero does attempt to at first during the surprise attack. He hits the ship hard and would have destroyed it if he hand't seen that it was the Enterprise out of all ships.

From the comics we knew he read the historical data of the federation and thus also knew that Spock served upon that ship and for Nero all revenge is best served cold.

Thus destroying the Enterprise would kill Spock way too early even if its only the young Spock. He wanted him to suffer thus he stopped the other barrages that would have destroyed the ship from being fired.

Else the second wave of Torpedoes would have done the Enterprise in (what is more surprising is that the Enterprise took less of a beating than the Kelvin and was in a way worse shape according to their own crew..."another hit like that and we are done for"!).

Answer (score -2):

The 2009 reboot ends Star Trek having basis in science or logic. It's now an action film more on the lines of Star Wars. (This is not of itself a bad thing). Hence the Enterprise surviving is required for the action and plot.

For example, once the enemy ship is bisected by a blackhole you no longer need to open fire with all weapons ..

Research used: http://redlettermedia.com/plinkett/star-trek/star-trek-09/ (Red Letter Media Review)

Comment: That doesn't really address the question, it's just your opinion; unless you have some evidence to back this up.

Comment: You could argue @Shadur's 3 point answer is merely his opinion of motives. It's fact that Star Trek no longer cares about cause and effect in its science hence why battles don't need to make logical sense, only plot sense.

Comment: But that's juts one third of his answer. If you want to say that it doesn't follow logic, then you should provide evidence for such. Give other examples from the film where this is the case, or perhaps a quote from a writer/producer saying as much.

Comment: As-is, your answer basically boils down to a "plot hole answer/rant", which the community has decided [are not useful](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/957/usefulness-of-plot-hole-answers-comments).

Comment: @Moogle, deciding ships caught in black holes require more shooting?

Comment: @phantom42 this isn't a plot hole. It's a change in direction for the franchise.

Comment: I didn't say it was a plot hole - I said that your answer currently boils down to that type. You're just saying, "because the director decided to do it that way."

Comment: OK- sometimes it goes down like that. I'll add a research link for you

Comment: "For example, once the enemy ship is bisected by a blackhole you no longer need to open fire with all weapons .." Black holes have been presented as escapable by ships with warp drive before (which makes a sort of sense, since physics just says nothing moving at speeds less than or equal to light can escape), see the Voyager ep Parallax: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Parallax_(episode)

Comment: @Hypnosifl "A ship is caught near the event horizon" is not the same as being bisected by the entire singularity. And I hesitate to point out that using pre-reboot science to argue about my statement that the reboot ditches science may become a bit unuseful to anyone.

Comment: @Paul --you are confusing the event horizon (the spherical region that light can't escape from) and the singularity (the infinitely dense point at the center), Nero's ship was bisected by the event horizon, not the singularity. And in that Voyager episode, the ship was *inside* the event horizon and later escaped it, it wasn't just "near" the horizon. My point is that this example is identical in its degree of scientific (im)plausibility as the Voyager episode, they both feature exactly the same premise that a warp-capable ship can escape outward from inside a black hole event horizon.

Comment: That's not research. It is just someone else's unsubstantiated claims presented as a 30 minute video with a silly voice and inane jokes.

Comment: This is in out-of-universe answer, is the main problem.

Comment: @Hypnosifl in order to be bisected by the event horizon it must have the singuarlity at the centre. Secondly, the word "near" comes from the link you provided. terdon it's an observation on the series direction, and an accurate one (it's also not intrinsically bad).

Comment: @Paul the singularity must be at the center of the black hole, but the ship itself can be bisected by the event horizon while being far from the singularity. The "act one" section of the link does say they first spot a ship "near" the horizon, but "act four" makes clear that they actually went through the event horizon, and need to find a "hole" in it to escape. If you look at the script at http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/102.htm this is even clearer: do a control-F (command-F on a Mac) to search for "event horizon" in the script, there are lines like "when we first entered the event horizon"

Comment: (continued from last comment because I ran out of characters) and Torres' line "If we could find our entry point, we might be able to slip out the way we came in" followed by Janeway's "So we'd be looking for a subspace instability in the event horizon." I don't want to comment on your broad characterization of the "series direction" because it's non-specific, my point is that if you're trying to use this SPECIFIC example to show there's less respect for science in Abrams Trek, it doesn't work since Voyager did exactly the same thing (of course Voyager may have had less respect than TNG etc.)

Answer (score -2):

From a purely practical standpoint, if Nero destroys the *Enterprise* in the first encounter, the movie is over--and so are any possible sequels.

Comment: Out-of-universe answers are generally frowned on. We all know it's because "a writer wrote it that way", the trick is to find out how they'd justify it.